# Problem with object geometry when applying bevel

Tags: geometry, bevel

When I apply bevel modifier to the mesh, some vertexes merge to the Origin point of the mesh  blowing up the geometry.
There are no doble vertexes, faces, ngons.
The Normals, Scale are correct.
I tryed to change the position of the Origin Point. The result is the same...
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I attache the link to the file below.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QulB3sW5kMNUZb4YZKCqe0MFJ4UqFTPI/view?usp=sharing

It could help possible.

I have the same type of problem in the other mesh.
[image]

If I delete some faces, the problem is solved.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, it seems to come with the _Bevel_ modifier, some setting there will be causing it. I guess there is something like a too high _Amount_ or similar whereas part of the geometry are too close. But although you suspected it has something to do with the bevel you didn't bother to show the modifier settings in your screenshot... that's a pity ;)

Comment: Okay, with the _Amount_ that's set and _Clamp Overlap_ enabled I can only imagine there are double vertices, flipped normals or any other geometry problems. In the question you say that you have checked for these options and there is nothing like that. Then I guess you should upload the file because without further inspection of the model it seems impossible to determine where the error is.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I attached two more screenshorts with open bevel settings. There are no close geometry. I turned on "Edge Lengh" so you can see the real size and proportios of the mesh

Comment: Thank you. I'll upload the file in a minute.

Comment: I've seen the screenshots with the edge length, but selecting one edge doesn't tell anything about the occluded edges there for example. Hence I said if the geometry is okay as you said, there is nothing more to find through screenshots.

Comment: I attache the link to Google Drive with the file uploaded. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QulB3sW5kMNUZb4YZKCqe0MFJ4UqFTPI/view?usp=sharing

Comment: It woks! Thank you very much! You saved my day! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a combination of different settings that don't like to be combined, as it seems...

For example, to get rid of this strange artifact you can do one of the following things, depending on what is best for you to work on with the model:

- disable *Clamp Overlap* (not necessary for this micro bevel, there's no overlapping)
- or set *Miter Outer* to *Sharp* instead of *Arc* (won't see the difference anyway on the small bevel)
- or close the side of the object (Does it have to be open? Filling the hole removes the artifact)